Convert JSON with various number of fields in .net
I have structure like this:
public enum Roles
{
ROLE_1,
ROLE_2,
ROLE_3,
...
ROLE_20
}

public enum Status
{
NONE,
ACTIVE,
REFUSE
...
}

Depend on user I can receive from API various number of roles in JSON like this:
{
    "ROLE_1": "NONE",
    "ROLE_2": "ACTIVE"
    "ROLE_3": "ACTIVE"
}

or
{
    "ROLE_2": "ACTIVE"
}

What is the best way to handle this in C# .Net? I was thinking about a dictionary but I don't  know how to serialize this properly.
I tried handle this with dynamic object, but maybe is the easier way to resolve this?

Deserialize to a Dictionary. What does your current model (deserialization-target) look like? And which Json Lib is in use (most common would probably be System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.JSON)?

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

// Deserialize the JSON into a dictionary
var roleStatuses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Roles, Status>>(json, settings);


You could create a dictionary out of Role and RoleStatus enums. And fill it as you wish, inside decleration or with functions.
private Dictionary<Role, RoleStatus> _roleStatuses = new();

Then you can set your json options.
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // For clean and readable indentation
    WriteIndented = true, 
    // Saving strings instead of indexes
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() } 
};

And then you can convert it to json.
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_roleStatuses, options);

And thats how you would deserialize it.
var deserializedRoleStatuses = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<Role, RoleStatus>>(jsonString, options);


Instead of creating Roles as enum create a new class and design it like this
public class RolesC
{
  public Status ROLE_1 {get;set;}

  public Status ROLE_2 {get;set;}
  .
  .
  .

  public Status ROLE_20 {get;set;}

}

Here you can see that the fields in RolesC class are all Status enum
Now you can simply deserialize yout json string into RolesC class

This needs to be maintained alongside the ROLES enum. Not the best of ideas (keeping roles in an enum, too but well ... )

What if with your example receive JSON which contain 21 roles? 210? You'll lose the data and probably won't notice it.
